# ASP.NET With Firebird database problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, firebird, edmx

Did you ever try to create a ASP.NET MVC Project with Firebird database...I try it, and is difficult..

My problem:

- I have working Firebird provider for Visual Studio 2010.
- I have correct database with all needed for increasing the id of the tables.
- I have created ASP.NET MVC 3 project, with included database, like EDMX file, with entities.
- When i try to insert a record into a table, there occurs a problem that says:

> FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException: violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint "PK_USERS" on table "USERS"

That means the id of the record that is created is not increased.
I have stored procedures that must generate new id.

My question is:
How to insert record in Firebird data table from ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2):

In Firebird you need to use triggers in combination with sequences (generators) if you want to have auto-increment like behavior. Otherwise you need to make sure that you assign a unique id yourself.

To create the sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mytable_id_sq;
```

To create a trigger for assigning a unique i (on a table called mytable)

```
set term !! ;
CREATE TRIGGER T1_BI FOR mytable
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
if (NEW.ID is NULL) then NEW.ID = NEXT VALUE FOR mytable_id_sq;
END!!
set term ; !!
```

This trigger will only assign a generated value if no ID is assigned in the `INSERT` statement.

See also:
section [`SEQUENCE` (`GENERATOR`)](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-sequence) in the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference and [How to create an autoincrement column?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq29/) (this link talks about generators, the old name of sequences in Firebird).

Comment: I have trigers and generators from the begining.
My triger is look like:
as
begin
  if (new.user_id is null) then
    new.user_id = gen_id(gen_users_id,1);
end

and my generato s look like:
begin
  id = gen_id(gen_employees_id, 1);
  suspend;
end

This is for the user table.

Comment: Then most likely your sequence/generator and table ids are out of sync: The sequence returns a value that already exists in your table. This can happen if you insert self assigned ids without using the generator.

Comment: OR, instead writting a lot of triggers, you can write directly: insert into TABLE (ID, ...) values (next value for YOUR_GENERATOR, ...);

Comment: @Marcodor That assumes that all developers writing the SQL will behave themselves ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your EDMX isn't probably generated properly. Either you have to set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` manually or use http://blog.cincura.net/230841-generated-primary-key-in-entity-framework-model-from-firebird/ .

Comment: I try it with switching the StoreGeneratedPattern to Computed, ot Identity, but dosen't work.
I solve the problem simply by adding this line before adding the user to the database: user.USER_ID = db.USERS.Max(x => x.USER_ID) + 1;